# Android external Jar

Tags: java, android, noclassdeffounderror

I have some api with **java** and I need it in my **android** app.

When I am using it with including all packages and classes it works fine. Now I create JAR file from my java project using export. Now when I add the jar to my android app as a external jar my all errors are disappeared but when I run my app I got an error

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.`

I have seen that kind of errors early in my apps and it was the problem of Jar. How can I generate JAR file to avoid this situation?

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: have you build your jar including references?

Comment: Double check in Eclipse BuildPath that your lib is "exported". It means that it will be dexed inside your apk. The last tab of BuildPath dialog, your lib must be checked.

Comment: Have you copied the jar to your <project root>/libs folder? If I remember right Android only uses that directory for external jars, even though you can add it to build path from anywhere in Eclipse.

Comment: include your jar in export list of build setting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have probably built that jar file with jdk 1.7. Classes compiled with jdk 1.7 are not included in apk file. Try to change java compiler to 1.6 before you export jar. In eclipse go to Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler.

Answer (score 2):

copy the jar file in the `libs` folder of your android project.

After that you may want to clean your project and rebuild it. You can even clear manually the bin dir content.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add your *jar* file to your project's buildpath.

To make sure it's exported in your APK, you also have to check it under the *Order and Export* tab, in the build path preferences of your project.

Answer (score 1):

A better approach might be the following:

1. remove the current exported jar from your project
2. select the project you want to import, right click -> properties -> android -> check 'mark as library'
3. right click your current project -> properties -> android -> locate the 'add' button in the bottom. Click it and select the library project.

Using this approach any changes in the library project will be reflected in your current project (at least after doing a clean projects).

Answer (score 0):

I have done it !!! Thanks everybody.
So the solution is :
1. change java compiler to 1.6 before you export jar (As @Lecho mentioned)
2. Move the Jar file to lib folder
So it works !!! thanks everybody